# Mavericks Screen Sharing resolution - Remmina VNC client

Tags: remmina

I am remoting into my MacBook Pro from an Ubuntu VNC client (Remmina). The screens I have for my ubuntu machine are much lower resolution then my retina display so the VNC session window is enormous.

Is there any way I can reduce the resolution for remote screen management or perhaps use a client that allows the remote session window in Ubuntu to be scaled so I can view the entire retina desktop on a single screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vinagre (available in the Ubuntu repositories, goes with the builtin VNC server Vino) supports scaling the screen down. However, even when scaled, VNC works at the host's real resolution; so you're still sending quite a lot of data over the network in this case.

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks!

It is annoying though that Vino enforces a password length limit of 8 characters...